# How do you trim or move the last letter of one column to another in excel. I have attached code

Tags: excel, parsing, trim

Good evening guys, Im trying to figure out how to move the last letter in one column to a new column in excel. I tried watching youtube vids and followed the code but it doesnt work. For example A:1 cell says "Susie B." sometimes it doesnt have the period and A2 may say "Susie B" How do I take just the last letter the column A cells you can include the period. I thought it would be something like "=RIGHT(A1, len(A1)-2)". I put -2 , to get the period as well just in case some cells had the period. I attached a screen shot as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),1)
```

[image]